# OOP Principles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am having some trouble working with oo javascript. I am creating a new object public and private methods. Now when I am calling the public method, it cannot access the private variable.

I believe I should `return` the public methods ( the internet ) but **dont really know why.**
Can someone please explain what I am missing?

```
function something(){
    var somePanel;  // it is a jquery object to a div

    var createWindow = function(data){
        random.xhr('/chat', 'GET', null, function(res){
            var Container = $("#Container");
            somePanel = $("<div/>").addClass('somePanel').append(res);
            Container.append(somePanel.hide());
        });     
    };

    this.activate = function(){
        somePanel.show().siblings().hide();
    };

    this.init = function(data, fn){
        createWindow(data);
    };
};


connections[data] = new something();  // creates a new something object
connections[data].init(data);   //  which creates just a div object, actually
connections[data].activate();  // has code to show this panel and hide every other panel
```

When I call the `activate()` method, it cannot find `somePanel`. What should I be doing differently? And why?

Comment: how do you define `somePanel` and where? try to explain it a bit more

Comment: this code runs perfectly good; you are not showing us the not working part. But I guess you used `var` somewhere hiding your original `somePanel` from `something`

Comment: Also, what is the unused "that" argument for in the activate method? Also, somePanel isn't defined, so I'm guessing you're seeing Uncaught TypeError exceptions due to the value being undefined, no?

Comment: updated with some comments of the code

Comment: I think you need to pass the reference to the somePanel variable, because your closure just declares the variable but never gets set, something like this should work: this.init = function( data, fnc, ref ){ /* your init code */ somePanel = ref; }

Comment: updated with some more code..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Ok, now with more code the problem is another one, the ajax call is asynch, which means that it is still being executed when the next method from your object is called, you need to provide some callbacks for keeping the workflow correctly. @meagar beat me to the example :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic problem with asynchronous methods.

You're xhr handler will not have been invoked when you run `activate`. You need to wait for your xhr handler to run, and then, in a callback, invoke `activate`.

Something along these lines:

```
// ...

this.init = function(data, fn){
    createWindow(data, fn);
};

var createWindow = function(data, fn) {
    random.xhr('/chat', 'GET', null, function(res){
        var Container = $("#Container");
        somePanel = $("<div/>").addClass('somePanel').append(res);
        Container.append(somePanel.hide());
        fn();
    });     
};

// ...

connections[data] = new something();
connections[data].init(data, function () { connections[data].activate() });
```

Comment: so my oo skills aren't to blame. glad :)

Comment: yes. i had created a callback function from the start for a different reason, however. came in handy. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you're setting `somePanel` in the callback to an async call. You can't be guaranteed `somePanel` is set by the time you call `activate()`.

*edit* meagar's answer is the best option from an OO perspective. The rest of my answer is aimed at maintaining the readability you're trying to achieve.

You may want to look into using a module that allows for asynchronous chaining (like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)) or [promises](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970)